# How to convert geojson string stored in a dataframe directly to sp?

Tags: r, r-sp

I've got a dataframe (dat) with a column called "geometry" containing geojson point, e.g. `{"type":"Point","coordinates":[100.1234,10.1234]}`

I am currently using the following code and it works.

```
library(sp)
library(sf)
dat$geometry<-do.call(rbind, lapply(as.character(dat$geometry), read_sf))
dat$geometry<-as(dat$geometry, "Spatial")
```

As a result, dat$geometry is of class "SpatialPointsDataFrame".

However, anybody know how to do the conversion solely with sp?

Comment: I would like to ask *why* you want an `sp` object, given you already have an `sf`?

Comment: @SymbolixAU, I was thinking leaflet only compatible with sf. I just realized it works with sf as well. Thank for your question.